# How to start Storyboard by means of data binding?

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have a *Storyboard* at Window resources as shown below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--  Storyboard as a window resource  -->
    <Storyboard
        x:Key="NB"
        x:Name="NB_resource"
        Completed="NB_resource_Completed"
        RepeatBehavior="5x">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetName="NB_image"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source"
            Duration="0:0:1.2">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/CircleSurrogateButton;component/Images/NB_00.png" />
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.3">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/CircleSurrogateButton;component/Images/NB_01.png" />
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.6">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/CircleSurrogateButton;component/Images/NB_02.png" />
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.9">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/CircleSurrogateButton;component/Images/NB_03.png" />
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

The Storyboard can be started with the following string which is placed in regular Button.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
 <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource NB}" />
 </EventTrigger>
```

A question is How to use a data binding in order to start that Storyboard.
For example:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Start_Storyboard}" Value="true">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource NB}"/>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
 </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: What's wrong with that DataTrigger?

Comment: Where do I have to put that to get it working?

Comment: The Storyboard seems to target a named element, NB_image. Put the DataTrigger into the Triggers of a Style for that element.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: I've tried, XAML doesn't show any red squiggles, however while compilation it throws an exeption.